# Rails Rake ENV variable alwaays empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, jruby

I have trouble using ENV variable in the database.yml and with rake.

The config file database.yml

```
development:
  <<: *default
  url: "mysql://user:pass@<%=ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
```

Launching the command

```
 jruby -S bundle exec rake assets:clean
```

with

```
URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme mysql does not accept registry part: user:pass@ (or bad hostname?)
```

Seems that DB_HOST is empty when rake runs, but it's definitively set in the system.

I'm using JRuby 6.3.1.
When launching the project in IntelliJ it works perfect.

Comment: _it's definitively set in the system_ : What is "the system", and how did you verify that it is set?

Comment: The system is the ubuntu 20.04 and was verified by echo $DB_HOST

Comment: Does `ENV['DB_HOST']` work in `rails console`? Is `database.yml` getting parsed via ERB?

Comment: `echo` does not tell you whether a variable is in the environment. Do a `printenv DB_HOST` instead.

Comment: Have you tried doing this? `url: "mysql://user:pass@#{ENV['DB_HOST']}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When not using the key "url" in database.yml it's working for me.

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%=ENV['DB_NAME'] %>
  host: <%=ENV['DB_HOST'] %>
```